# How to make soft delete and set column deleted=true instead of real user deleting from database?

Tags: java, rest, http-delete

I want to make soft deleting by adding the additional column delete=true instead of real user deleting from database.
I have the following method in `UserServiceImpl`:

```
@Override
public void deleteUser(String id) {
    UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findById(Integer.valueOf(id))
            .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("Id not found"));
    if (userEntity.getLastAccessDate() == null) {
        throw new ProhibitedScimTypeException("Broken policy");
    }
    userRepository.delete(userEntity);
}
```

In `UserController` I have:

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "204", content = {@Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = UserResource.class))}, description = "Successful")
})
@DeleteMapping("/Users/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    userService.deleteUser(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

And in `UserRepository` I've added the following method:

```
@Query("update UserEntity u set deleted = true where u = :u")
void delete(UserEntity userEntity);
```

Without this method in repository it didn't set true in `deleted` but using `void delete` I catch the mistake `Using named parameters for method not found in annotated query 'update user set deleted = true where user = :user'`.
Could you give me the piece of advice - what is the correct way to make this soft deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reference to the parameter `userEntity` in your `@Query` is incorrect. It should be:

```java
@Query("update UserEntity u set deleted = true where u = :userEntity")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And I've added @Modifying to make it works correctly